# Visual Studio default action for file removal

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, when a file is selected and "del" key is pressed, a dialog pops up and asks the user to choose whether he/she wants to remove or delete the file. And there is a little checkbox to select that choice as the default action. When the default action is selected, "del" key performs the same thing all the time.

Is there a way to cancel this default action? I've searched everywhere but couldn't find where this setting is held.

Thanks.

Comment: In default Visual Studio installation, there is no checkbox to select that choice as the default action.

Comment: But sometimes a dialog pops up to select remove or delete. And sometimes it just removes the file. How may I fix that?